# Why are session variables not storing in PHP for my code?

Tags: php

There are my both codes where error is,where the session variable is not executed in `session2.php` page and these are the errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: favcolor in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\vehiclebazar\session2.php on line 10
>   Favorite color is .
>   Notice: Undefined index: favanimal in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\vehiclebazar\session2.php on line 11
>   Favorite animal is .

session1.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> //html type
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

2nd page is

session2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why in single quotes? `'$'` just remove them! Also The comment style: `//` only works in php tags in html use: `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: kindly answer this question

Comment: You really should stop with the STEALTH edits. That means, overwriting your question with codes without marking them as edits. My answers works; period.

Comment: finaly it is orginal code

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's getting very time better and your answer longer.

Comment: @NoumanMalik Well, I've tested your code even before all your edits; the result was conclusive: SUCCESS.

Comment: @Fred-ii- .  .. then corect me . .where i am wrong

Comment: @Rizier123 OP's probably/most likely taking my code or others and overwriting the answer.

Comment: it is browser issue? @Fred-ii-

Comment: You've probably something on the server's cache and/or browser. Clear that, destroy previous sessions and upload new files under different names.

Comment: i work on localhost @Fred-ii-

Comment: Then make sure that the sessions folder is writeable and that proper permissions are given. That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: i m not properly understand ur last coment .i dont know these terms u talking about  .what is that permission means?. . . @Fred-ii-

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/19906784/ - your folder that the sessions are supposed to be written to, must be writeable. Meaning that, PHP must have permission to write to the folder in question. You have your settings in your `.ini` files and should look into those to see what they are and what they're set to. Add error reporting to the top of your files, as I stated in an additional edit in my answer below. You can further your research on Google for "folder file permissions php sessions".

Comment: Nouman, aside from Fred's advice about not substantively changing a question while it is being answered, it would also be good if you would stick to informative titles. Try to keep these succinct and free from chat (no "I am a beginner") as that's not of use to other people who may learn from this question in the future. I've edited it for you now.

Answer (score 6):

This, as per your initial/original post and not marking it as an edit, including all other edits you've made.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27758846/1

which your edit still contains a quote `$'_SESSION["favcolor"]` between `$` and `_`

---

You see these `'$'_SESSION` they can't contain quoted dollar signs.

All of those need to read as `$_SESSION` in one go, which is why you're getting those warnings.

Read up on this superglobal

- **http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php**

These superglobal variables are:

```
$GLOBALS
$_SERVER
$_GET
$_POST
$_FILES
$_COOKIE
$_SESSION
$_REQUEST
$_ENV
```

---

Also, in your first file, you have

```
<?php//opening of php
```

that alone will throw an error, had you [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set. Either remove the `//opening of php` or put it in a second line:

```
<?php 
//opening of php
```

The error in question:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE)...

---

While testing your code and after fixing all of those errors, did in fact post

```
Favorite color is green.
Favorite animal is cat.
```

in the second file.

You should make it a habit not to have comments so close to executable code, ***especially*** the opening `<?php` tag.

Another being `session_start();//where session start` it won't throw/cause an error, but it's just confusing.

---

You could also check if both sessions are set:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["favcolor"]) && isset($_SESSION["favanimal"])){
    echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
}

else{
    echo "Sessions are not set.";
}
```

Plus, since you said you were doing this via localhost, make sure that the sessions/tmp folder(s) are writeable and have proper write permissions set.

Use:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

in a seperate file to see what your sessions settings are set to.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Or perhaps read up on variables in php in general.

Comment: lol he just updated the question and now it's only 1 quote he has too much

Comment: @Rizier123 You gotta love those stealth edits lol

Comment: @Rizier123 Stealth edit number.... I lost count.

Comment: Phew, you have far too much patience, Fred! Great effort, well done.

Comment: @halfer Lord as my witness, knows I try. Thanks. Oh, and I grow "cactus" lol so I do have a lot of patience.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **$_SESSION["favcolor"]** not  '$'_SESSION["favcolor"]

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: i correct them but still warrning . .

Comment: if your code is right up there still have $'_SESSION["favcolor"]. You should change $_SESSION["favcolor"]

Answer (score 0):

```
'$'_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
'$'_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Favorite color is " . '$'_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . '$'_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
```

In PHP, a variable should look like `$var`, not `'$'var`.  So instead of `'$'_SESSION["favcolor"]` and `'$'_SESSION["favanimal"]` use `$_SESSION["favcolor"]` and `$_SESSION["favanimal"]`.

Further reading on PHP variables:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php